# hostname not translated into an IP address using Winsock

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, winsock

`getaddrinfo()` does not translate a hostname into an IP address and consequently does not `connect()` to the server. Is something wrong with my implementation - compiles with no warning messages?

Is this function call to `connect` correct?

```
connect(client, result->ai_addr, result->ai_addrlen)
```

Full implementation listed below:

```
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")

using namespace std;

int main (
          int argc,
          char* argv[])
{
if (argc != 3)
{
    cerr << "Usage: " << argv[0] << " [hostname] [port number]\n";
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

WSADATA wsaData;
WORD wVersionRequested;
int wError;

wVersionRequested = MAKEWORD(2, 2);

wError = WSAStartup(wVersionRequested, &wsaData);

if (wError != 0)
{
    cerr << "WSAStartup failed with error: " << wError << endl;
    exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
}

/*
* Confirm that the WinSock DLL supports 2.2.
* Note that if the DLL supports versions greater
* than 2.2 in addition to 2.2, it will still return 
* 2.2 in wVersion since that is the version we 
* requested. 
*/

if (LOBYTE(wsaData.wVersion) != 2 || HIBYTE(wsaData.wVersion) != 2)
{
    cerr << "Could not find a usable version of Winsock.dll." << endl;
    WSACleanup();
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
} else {
    cout << "The Winsock 2.2 dll was found." << endl;
}

SOCKET client;

if ((client = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
{
    cerr << "Error: socket() return value == SOCKET_ERROR" << endl;
    WSACleanup();
    exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
}

cout << "Created a socket." << endl;

struct addrinfo *result = NULL;
struct addrinfo hints;
memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(hints));
hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;

if ((wError = getaddrinfo(
                    argv[1],
                    argv[2],
                    &hints,
                    &result)) !=0 )
{
    freeaddrinfo(result);
    WSACleanup();
    if (wError == 11001)
    {
        cerr << "Error: occurred: getaddrinfo() failed "
             << wError << " - Host not found." << endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    cerr << "Error: occurred: getaddrinfo() failed "
            << wError << endl;
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
/*
* Attempt to connect to the Server
*
*/

switch (wError = connect(client, result->ai_addr, result->ai_addrlen)) {
    case 0:
        cerr << "Resolved hostname." << endl;
        break;
    case SOCKET_ERROR:
        wError = WSAGetLastError();
        cerr << "Error: connet() failed "
                "Details: " << wError << endl;
        closesocket(client);
        freeaddrinfo(result);
        WSACleanup();
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        break;
    default:
        cerr << "Fatal connect() error: unexpected "
                "return value." << endl;
        closesocket(client);
        freeaddrinfo(result);
        WSACleanup();
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        break;
}

cout << "Connected to server." << endl;

closesocket(client);
freeaddrinfo(result);
WSACleanup();
exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: How are you running it? I copied your code directly and built it, then ran "testresolve stackoverflow.com 80" and it correctly resolved the host and made a connection.

Comment: Interesting: The server will run on a separate machine on a specified port. On the command-line: "hostname" returns SAMPLE. Using the implementation above: SAMPLE 1234 - Error: connet() failed Details: 10061

Comment: 10061 = WSAECONNREFUSED, which implies that the hostname WAS resolved, but there is nothing listening on that port number.

Comment: Thanks! However, from the server end: status listening on port X - for instance is works: if server is listening on port 1234 - client: 127.0.0.1 1234 - this works fine not: SAMPLE 1234 - strange?

Comment: Are you sure that the given port is open for access from outside ?

Comment: Check your firewall settings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`getaddrinfo` may be giving you an IPv6 address, or perhaps the machine has more than one IP address and you're trying to connect to the wrong one.

Also, if your server is listening on 127.0.0.1 and you try to connect to the real IP address, the connection will fail. Similarly, if the server is listening on the real IP address and you try to connect using 127.0.0.1, the connection will fail. If the server listens on 0.0.0.0, both addresses should work.

To listen on 0.0.0.0, you would have code similar to this:

```
sockaddr_in sin;
sin.sin_family = AF_INET;
sin.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
sin.sin_port=htons( port_num );
bind( s, (sockaddr *)&sin, sizeof( sin ) );
```

Comment: How to set the server to listen on 0.0.0.0?

Comment: This is my first Socket implementation on Windows :( I have much to learn :)

Comment: You pass the address to listen on into the bind() call before calling listen. You can use INADDR_ANY as a shortcut.

Comment: Updated the answer to include this.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the `hint.ai_family` to `AF_UNSPEC` instead of `AF_INET`, I believe that when `AF_INET` is specfied the getaddrinfo functions excepts IPv4-like address.

Comment: OK: if hostname is "SAMPLE", if passed as an argument - doesn't work but as an IP address (on local machine) it works: such as 127.0.0.1

Comment: Are you sure that the provided hostname is valid ?

Comment: From the cmd-line: hostname returns SAMPLE
so: SAMPLE 1234 (where the server is running) returns:
Error: connet() failed Details: 10061

Comment: Ok, is the port you provided correct ? Error 10061 means 'connection refused' which usually is a sign of wrongly chosen port.

Comment: Yes confirmed: TCP, Local port 1234, local address 127.0.0.1 - but not sure why: 127.0.0.1 1234 - works but not: SAMPLE 127.0.0.1 - as SAMPLE is hostname?

Comment: It maybe a typo but: with SAMPLE 127.0.0.1 the app is trying to connect to a SAMPLE host on port 127.0.0.1 - which is invalid.